# Custom views twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to create a new twig template that defines different types of views templates - or some sort of option based format.

**Example 1**:

Generic view blocks: *block--views-block.html.twig*

**Example 2**:

News Block specific views with no container: *block--views-block--news-elements-block-1.html.twig*

**Example 3**:

List Block specific views with no container: *block--views-block--list-elements-block-1.html.twig*

**What i want to achieve**: - if i can present an option on the block, that would also work.

Views block with no container: *block--views--no-container--block.html.twig*

So far:

```
function THEME_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  // dpm($variables);

  // $content = $variables['elements']['content'];
  // if (isset($content['#block_content']) && $content['#block_content'] instanceof \Drupal\block_content\BlockContentInterface) {
  //   $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $content['#block_content']->bundle();
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my circumstance i have adopted to use the `block_alter` hook to define the new suggestion for the template. Since homepage only contains the unique views template and the others wouldn't.

```
function THEME_theme_suggestions_block_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $path_check = \Drupal::service('path.matcher');

  if (in_array("block__views", $suggestions) && $path_check->isFrontPage() == FALSE ) {
    $suggestions[] = 'block__views__blah__custom';
  }

}
```